# Jquery dynamic element binding

Tags: javascript, jquery

Not long ago i posted a question about this and the solution was to add body as parent like this;

```
$("#registerF,body").on("change", "input,  select", function () {});
```

The #registerF element was dynamically loaded and adding body to it fixed the issue.

However I am facing the same problem now and adding body is not working.

I am working on a text editor that uses BBcode just like this one on StackOverflow.  Everything is working when I load that page. But when I load it dynamically it is not working and adding body is not working.

Here is the first fonction as an example:

```
$("#textEdit").on("focus", function () {
    var text = document.getElementById('textEdit');
    text.onkeyup = text.onkeypress = function () {
        preview = this.value;
        preview = bbToHtml(preview);
        document.getElementById('editorPreview').innerHTML = preview;
    }
});
```

I try several thing like:

```
$("#textEdit, body").on("focus", function () {

$("body > #textEdit").on("focus", function () {
```

Nothing is working in this case. I wonder why it is not working for this but it work's for my form registerF element.

**EDIT**

I think that what causes the problem is the `this` statement.

Most of it is working but this part:

```
$(document).click('#textEdit,.editBout', function (e) {
    //$("#editToolBar,.editBout").click(function (e) { <-------was
    alert('clicked');   <------------get triggered even if i dont click
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log(this); <-----------------------------return #document
    var style = ($(this).attr("data-style"));  <---- So this is not working
```

So instead of this i passed it the element:

```
 var style = ($('#textEdit,.editBout').attr("data-style"));  <----Work but not dynamiccaly
```

So its working but still not working if i load in dynamically. the Click is not getting triggered.

Comment: Try `$(document).on('focus', '#textEdit', function(e) {`

Comment: Try adding a `console.log($("#textEdit, body"))` just above the line with `$.on()`, and confirm you see the element you are expecting in the console.

Comment: @Tushar Yes that worked Thank you very much sir

Comment: Actually its is not all working see my edit.

Comment: Could it be because i use the class name .editBout?

Comment: console.log($("#textEdit, body"));  return illegal return statement,